# Does Bitcoin-Qt require that I create a bitcoin.conf file in order to solo mine on my Mac?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, solo-mining, bitcoin.conf

Does `Bitcoin-Qt` require that I create a `bitcoin.conf` file in order to solo mine on my Mac?  I created one after reading the wiki and placed it in `Lib/AppSupp/Bitcoin` but I am not sure I needed to.  Was I correct in creating this file?  If not, what application besides `Bitcoin-Qt` is it used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, `bitcoin.conf` is a configuration file to set various options of the bitcoin client.  Details of the file and available options can be found [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin).

The most commonly used option is to set the RPC username and password ([see your other question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24756/bitcoin-conf-json-rpc-options/24759#24759)).  If you only want to solo mine using `setgenerate true` (which, as I mentioned in [my other answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/24759/5757) is not recommended), the defaults should be fine and you don't need to put anything in `bitcoin.conf`.

Comment: Indeed, Mr. Eldredge, the wiki is where I got my template for the .conf file!  Your answer is unclear to me, however.  First you say that the most commonly used option is to "set the RPC username and password" and then you say the "defaults should be fine," however the defaults do not have the user and password activated.  Can you clarify?  (I should also mention that I did not state that I only intend to mine with setgenerate true. I do, however, want to know how to do so regardless of this impractibility.)

Comment: @oemb1905: Well, you only need to set the RPC username and password if you intend to use the RPC API with some external software.  Your other posts suggest that you don't plan to do that, in which case you do not need to set them.

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far and please answer future questions as well.  My questions are designed to clarify set-up facts and will not necessarily have anything to do with my preferred method of mining.  Again, much obliged.  Regards, oemb1905

Comment: So just to clarify, the nodes are who the RPC client connects to, so I use the trusted nodes wiki to establish who I want to enter in that field?  And the peers below that refers to the machine I have running the client, so I enter my local manually assigned IP address there?